# Using JSON Associative Array to Add Event Listeners to Multiple Elements

Tags: javascript, json, dom-events

I am using JavaScript to iterate through a JSON associative array to add an event listener to a collection of different forms on the same page. The key of the array is the ID of the object on the page and the value is the message to appear in a confirmation box when the form is submitted.

For example ,I have a series of forms with IDs: `confirm_1`, `confirm_2`, `confirm 2`.

On the same page I have something like this:

```
<script type="application/json" id="json_data">{"confirm_1": "Are you sure?", "confirm_2": "Really?", "confirm_3": "Must you?"}</script>
<script src="confirmation.js"></script>
```

And this is `confirmation.js`:

```
var data = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('json_data').innerHTML);

for (var key in data) {
   document.getElementById(key).addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
      if (!confirm(data[key])) {
         event.preventDefault();
      }
   });
};
```

The problem is that when I click the submit button on any form they are all assigned the confirmation message of the final element in the array. It's like all the previous addEventListener calls inherit the last call made.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are facing issue because you have declared `key` as `var` datatype. Since it has function scope, it gets updated with the last value assigned to it which is `confirm_3` in your case. This problem can be solved in different ways. I will now mention three ways to solve it.

1. If you are okay with using ES6, you could just use `let` instead of `var` to declare `key` variable. Since `let` has block scope, each loop block will have its own space for `key` variable.
2. By binding the value to the callback function.
3. By using Immediate Invoke function.

I have addressed all these in the example below and have commented them for readability.

```js
var data = {
  confirm_1: "Are you sure?",
  confirm_2: "Really?",
  confirm_3: "Must you?"
};

//Using let
/*for (let key in data) {
  document
    .getElementById(key)
    .addEventListener("click", function (event) {
      alert(data[key]);
    });
}*/


//Using Bind
for (var key in data) {
  document.getElementById(key).addEventListener(
    "click",
    function (message, event) {
      alert(message);
    }.bind(this, data[key])
  );
}

//Using IIF (Immediate Invoking function)

/* for (var key in data) {
  (function(message){
     document
    .getElementById(key)
    .addEventListener("click", function (event) {
      alert(message);
    });
  })(data[key]);
} */
```

```html
<button id='confirm_1'>confirm_1</button>
<button id='confirm_2'>confirm_2</button>
<button id='confirm_3'>confirm_3</button>
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you for the quick and helpful reply. Could you recommend a particular approach? In particular, would there be compatibility issues with any of them for people using older browsers?

Comment: @Euler13 Using 'let' will be compatibility issues with old browsers. You can go with the second approach using 'bind'.

Comment: That's good to know. Thank you. And many thanks once again for your detailed and helpful answer. It is very much appreciated.